# Check Google script quota usage in real time

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to have stats on my quota usage for google scripts (those accessible from https://script.google.com/)

Since there are a lot of quota enforcements (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), it seems strange that Google does not allow users to check their usage against those quotas. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of December 7th, 2021 there is only one quota that has a Google Apps Script built-in way to be checked: Remaining daily email [MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getremainingdailyquota).

For all other quotas the Google Apps Script user should implement their own relevant quota usage tracker. This might be impossible for users of add-ons and web apps executed as the user running the app that are developed by others if they don't have access as editors to the corresponding Google Apps Script projects.

Related

- [How does daily Google Apps Script services quota limit apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17875014/1595451) (posted in 2013)
- [Where can I view Google Apps Script quota usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38205874/1595451) (posted in 2016)
- [Tracking total execution time Google apps script for an account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46883691/1595451) (posted in 2017)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas